# How do I list absolutely every keyboard shortcut that Ubuntu/Gnome is using?

Tags: gnome, keyboard, shortcut-keys

Sometimes there are shortcut key that I cannot see in settings (e.g., emoji key, or app overview, normally bound to ). So I've been looking for a way to list all shortcut keys. gsettings seems to have most, but e.g. dash-to-panel only uses dconf. I'm posting my own answer below, but perhaps somebody knows a more comprehensive answer?

Answer (score 1):

This perl script lists all settings that gsettings and dconf knows about.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
@s = split /\n/, `gsettings list-schemas`;
print "gsettings";
foreach (@s) {
    system "gsettings list-recursively $_";    
};
print "dconf";
print `dconf dump /`;
```

For a more comprehensive script, see here: https://github.com/bjohas/Ubuntu-keyboard-map-like-OS-X/tree/master/scripts

Answer (score 1):

For gsettings this works too:

```sh
gsettings list-schemas | while read schema; do gsettings list-recursively $schema; done;
```

Lol, scratch that, this works identical ;-)

```sh
gsettings list-recursively
```