# How to find and edit all keybindings for Ubuntu 21.04?

Tags: shortcut-keys, 21.04

I'm hoping to list all keybindings in Ubuntu 21.04 which would also show the ones not displayed by:

```
gsettings list-recursively org.freedesktop.ibus.general.hotkey
gsettings list-recursively org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings
gsettings list-recursively org.gnome.mutter.keybindings
gsettings list-recursively org.gnome.mutter.wayland.keybindings
gsettings list-recursively org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys
gsettings list-recursively org.gnome.shell.keybindings
```

For example, the binding <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> really messes up text input in some programs, but I cannot find a way to disable it. Don't know where else to look for it.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `gsettings list-recursively` to list all the GSettings properties. Then use `grep` to find what you are looking for.

```
gsettings list-recursively | grep Control
```

In my case I did not know the name of the keybinding which causes the undesired behavior. So I just listed everything containing the <kbd>CTRL</kbd> key. Had an output of around 10 lines and found what I was looking for:

```
org.freedesktop.ibus.panel.emoji unicode-hotkey ['<Control><Shift>u']
```

Then disabled the keybinding using:

```sh
gsettings set org.freedesktop.ibus.panel.emoji unicode-hotkey "[]"
```

---

<sup>The original solution used a script, but thanks to N0rbert's comment, this answer is now heavily simplified.</sup>

Comment: Tooooooooo difficult. Single command is possible - `gsettings list-recursively  | grep Control | grep ibus`  .

Answer (score 0):

I'm always bugged by these gnome shortcuts that occupy <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+(<kbd>Up</kbd> or <kbd>Down</kbd>).  This fixes it for me using NixOS syntax

```haskell
  # Gnome settings tweaks
  systemd.user.services.gsettings = {
    script = ''
      gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.vm.keybindings move-to-workspace-down "[''']"
      gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.vm.keybindings move-to-workspace-up "[''']"
      gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-down "[''']"
      gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-up "[''']"
    '';
    wantedBy = [ "graphical-session.target" ];
    partOf = [ "graphical-session.target" ];
  };
```

See also [How do I list absolutely every keyboard shortcut that Ubuntu/Gnome is using?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1213852/how-do-i-list-absolutely-every-keyboard-shortcut-that-ubuntu-gnome-is-using/1486760#1486760)